# How do I implement random direction change on my pygame enemy?

Tags: python, pygame

So I currently have an enemy class that moves left, encounters the end of the screen, then flips direction 180 degrees and walks right. It does this constantly.

I wish to make it randomly change direction, so it's more unpredictable. The issue I'm encountering is when I implement a random number generator for the distance of direction, how would I then inherit it into a variable when I create the instance? Or is there a more efficient way to do this? 
Entire enemy class:

```
class enemy(object):#need to use self to access these
    walkRight = [pygame.image.load('Game/R1E.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/R2E.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/R3E.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/R4E.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/R5E.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/R6E.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/R7E.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/R8E.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/R9E.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/R10E.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/R11E.png')]
    walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('Game/L1E.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/L2E.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/L3E.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/L4E.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/L5E.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/L6E.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/L7E.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/L8E.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/L9E.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/L10E.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/L11E.png')]

    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,end): #get R3E png
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.end = end
        self.path = [self.x,self.end]
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.vel = 3

    def draw(self,window): #enemy is gonna move from left, to right, left, to right etc between 2 co ordinate points
        self.move()
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 33: #if sign is changed, as walkcount would always be less than 33, it wouldn't change
            self.walkCount = 0

        #rather than using self.left, sel.right, we can use out velocity
        if self.vel > 0: #this means we're moving right, integer division 3 so it doesn't look like we going too fast
            window.blit(self.walkRight[self.walkCount //3],(self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        else:
            window.blit(self.walkLeft[self.walkCount //3],(self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1 #if not moving right, we're moving left


        #check if we're drawing an image to the left or right


    def move(self): #move method #to change directions, he needs to change velocity (multiply by -1 etc)

        if self.vel > 0:
            if self.x < self.path[1] + self.vel:#check if he's about to move past the point on screen, we're accessing the self.end eleme
                self.x += self.vel
            else: #e.g. if it's greater than, we change direction
                self.vel = self.vel * -1 #flipped 180 degrees, so goes other direction
                self.x += self.vel
                self.walkCount = 0
        else: #if our vel is negative
            if self.x > self.path[0] - self.vel:
                self.x += self.vel #vel is gonna be negative already if we've changed directions
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.x += self.vel
                self.walkCount = 0
```

Movement function:

```
def move(self): #move method #to change directions, he needs to change velocity (multiply by -1 etc)

        if self.vel > 0:
            if self.x < self.path[1] + self.vel:#check if he's about to move past the point on screen, we're accessing the self.end eleme
                self.x += self.vel
            else: #e.g. if it's greater than, we change direction
                self.vel = self.vel * -1 #flipped 180 degrees, so goes other direction
                self.x += self.vel
                self.walkCount = 0
        else: #if our vel is negative
            if self.x > self.path[0] - self.vel:
                self.x += self.vel #vel is gonna be negative already if we've changed directions
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.x += self.vel
                self.walkCount = 0
```

Creating the instance just before the main loop(x,y,height,width,walk distance):

```
goblin = enemy(0,440,64,64,450)
```

My attempt - still only takes one random number & permanently uses it whilst the game runs.

```
def timerthing():
    pathenemy = random.randint(0,450)
    return pathenemy



#now to write main loop which checks for collisions, mouse events etc
#make path randomly change
man = player(200,444,64,66) #creates instance of the player / object
goblin = enemy(0,440,64,64,timerthing())#need to create instance of enemy so he appears on the screen, path ends at timerthing
run = True
bullets = []
while run: 
    clock.tick(15) #frame rate

    timerthing()
```

Instead of a constant of 450, I'm after a constantly changing variable instead, so his movement is unpredictable. Any other suggestions would be appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def timerthing():
    pathenemy = random.randint(0,450)
    time.sleep(1)
    return pathenemy
```

But I suspect that's not really your problem.  It sounds like you have a configuration problem rather than a source problem, and to solve that we'd need an entirely different kind of information from you.

Comment: Yeah I just realised this as I got out - it was a problem with me importing random which I’ve now fixed, but still getting the same issue of it fetches one random number & uses that permanently as the end path.

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `timerthing()` more than once (have you stepped through it multiple iterations in a single debug session)?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do code this randomly moving enemy, I would implement two methods first:

- One method that returns the possible directions my enemy can go through, given the state of the board. Yet I can't help you with that, since we don't have the "board" part of your code. Let's call this method getPossibleDirections()
- One method move, with one argument direction, representing the direction taken by my enemy. Let's call this method move(direction)

Based on your code, I guess you can implement these two methods by yourself. And maybe you want your ennemy to move in the y direction too?

Like @Mark Storer said, you could use the random package, but I will use the random part of the numpy library (already included in python) for my answer:

```
# you will need to import numpy in the beginning of your file
import numpy as np

class enemy(...)
# your code goes there

    def getPossibleDirections(self):
        #your implementation
        pass

    def move(self, direction):
        #your implementation
        pass

    def moveRandomly(self):
        possibleDirections = self.getPossibleDirections()
        chosenDirection = np.random.randint(0,len(possibleDirections))
        # returns one number between 0 and len(possibleDirections) (not included) that can represent your direction
        self.move(possibleDirection[chosenDirection])
```

To move your ennemy randomly, you will just have to call enemy.moveRandomly().